# Leaflet: I want to have a dropdown filter selection box using feature properties as options

Tags: javascript, filter, combobox, leaflet, geojson

I am relatively new with `leaftlet` and `Javascript`, but I am making my little advances with a lot of research and patience.

But now, I have this doubt, I had a `geojson` with state information and a status information. So I need to put one Icon for each of status information and this I have already done, but I also need to have a dropfown filter selection box, with the state information as option, so If a select one State, I can only see the registers of this selection and of course I need to preserve the custom icons for every status.

How can I achieve it using `leaflet`? Is that possible? I have already achieved the combo selection box with custom options, but I had failed when tried to use this selection as filter in my data.

Here is my code:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([-23.589262,-46.619145], 10);
     L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
     attribution: 'Mapas &copy; OpenCycleMap, Dados do Mapa &copy; contribuidores do OpenStreetMap'
     }).addTo(map);

    function nomeando (feature, layer){
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.NAME)
    }   


    L.geoJson (PTS_TESTE,{
            onEachFeature: nomeando
     ,
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
     iconSize: [27, 27],
     iconAnchor: [13, 27],
     popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
     iconUrl: 'images/torre.jpg'

                });
                var smallIcon2 = new L.Icon({
     iconSize: [27, 27],
     iconAnchor: [13, 27],
     popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
     iconUrl: 'images/telefone.jpg'
                });
                if (feature.properties.STATUS == 'TORRE') {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
                    } 
                    else {return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon2});}
    }}).addTo(map)




var legend = L.control({position: 'topright'});
legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML = '<select><option>RJ</option><option>SP</option><option>MG</option></select>';
    div.firstChild.onmousedown = div.firstChild.ondblclick = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
    return div;
};
legend.addTo(map);
```

// This part here, I have tried to change change function to erase my layer first.

```
$('select').change(function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
     if (value == "RJ") {
     map.removeLayer(PTS_TESTE);}
});
```

Comment: Please paste the code of what have you done so far, or create a  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I have already posted the code.